# Set (content) approval status in workflow [Sharepoint 2013]

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have a custom list with approved and not-approved items.

Now I created a workflow that changes the value of one of the fields.

Problem is: After running that workflow, the Approval Status of this item is automatically set to "Pending". But I don't want to change this status.

I tried to switch on/off the checkbox "Automatically update the workflow status to the current stage name" but no effect.
I also tried to set the variable inside the work flow:

```
Set Variable: ApprovStatus to CurrentElement:Approval Status

then Update item in CurrentElement

then Set Workflow Status to Variable: ApprovStatus


Go to End of Workflow
```

How can I keep the current Approval Status (or set it to the value that it was before)?

When a item is (manually) approved, will it also work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
Solution was to use a Sharepoint **2010** workflow instead of 2013:

```
    Set Variable: AprSt to Current Element:Approval Status
    Update item in Current Element
    If Variable: AprSt not equals 0;#Approved
        Set content approval status to Pending with comments
    Else
        Set content approval status to Approved with comments
```

Now it works.